# jQuery Span - OnClick Change Background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some jQuery that when user click on span (which is inside li), change background-image of that span,and on next click,return the old background-image?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.inverse').click(function () {
        if($(this).find('.inverse').attr('id') == 'yes') {
            $(this).find('.inverse').attr('id', '').css('background-image' 'url(...)');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.inverse').attr('id', 'yes').css('background-image' 'url(...)');
        }
    });
});
```

And also HTML:

```
                <div class="dynamic">
                <h3>08/25/2014 - All Events</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Time<span class="inverse">Customer</span></li>
                        <li>7 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span></li>
                        <li>9 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span></li>
                        <li>11PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span></li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this but it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a site to "code this for me" this question is pretty basic and you will find the asnwer if you search a little

Comment: Put the code which you have tried

Comment: I'm very sorry if it sounds that way, but I've already lost a lot of time trying to find an adequate solution.

Comment: OP then please include your actual code and try so we can help U understand why isn't working

Comment: You will need a combination of a `.click()` handler and the `.toggleClass()` method.

Comment: Also your HTML structure ..

Comment: you can make use of .dbclick()

Comment: all spans has the same background?

Comment: Yes,all spans has the same background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is handle the change with a class name *(better than an ID)* and then check if the class is present or not. Also take care with the use of the quotes `".."` and `'..'` setting the `background-image`. Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inverse').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('actin')) {
      $(this).css('background','url("http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports")');
      $(this).toggleClass('actin');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background','url("http://lorempixel.com/200/100/food")');
      $(this).toggleClass('actin');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports') no-repeat;
  padding:15px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic">
  <h3>08/25/2014 - All Events</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Time<span class="inverse">Customer</span>
    </li>
    <li>7 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
    <li>9 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
    <li>11PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

Also if you jsut want to handle on the click the `bg` you can just add a class changing that background:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inverse').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('actin');
  });
});
```

```css
.inverse {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports') no-repeat;
  padding:15px;
  color:white;
}
.inverse.actin {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100/food') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic">
  <h3>08/25/2014 - All Events</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Time<span class="inverse">Customer</span>
    </li>
    <li>7 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
    <li>9 PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
    <li>11PM<span class="inverse">Customer Name</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,this working!Thank you so much!The main problem in my knowledge is exactly this "Also take care with the use of the quotes ".." and '..' setting the background-image."

Comment: Yep @Peky27 I guess was that on your code check the edit for a simple way to do that change :)

Comment: Yes,even better!Thank you so much,again!Very easy to understand and implement for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't show us what you've tried I only explain the logic for this and some useful tips.

First of all, to catch a `click` event in `jQuery` you can user `.click` function, which also has a handler parameter. Read more [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

So, first step is to add an event for span click like `$('yourspan').click(function(){});`.

Second step: Inside the function above you can write your code to change `background`. You can do this with `jQuery` using `.css` function. Read more `http://api.jquery.com/css/`. There's a much better alternative to this by using `css classes`. Think about it.